# Rest client code throwing exception

Tags: java, rest

I am trying to call a web service
It reads the file simpleio.txt.toHCP from the local directory and writes it to HCP.Then turns around and reads the object back out into file simpleio.txt.fromHCP.
but I am getting exception as below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.HttpHost.getAddress()Ljava/net/InetAddress;
at org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoute.normalize(HttpRoute.java:106)
at org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoute.<init>(HttpRoute.java:74)
at org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoute.<init>(HttpRoute.java:170)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpRoutePlanner.determineRoute(DefaultHttpRoutePlanner.java:116)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:762)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:381)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
at com.hds.hcp.examples.SimpleIO.WriteToHCP(SimpleIO.java:117)
at com.hds.hcp.examples.SimpleIO.main(SimpleIO.java:218)
```

The code is

```
void WriteToHCP() throws Exception {
    /*
     * Setup the PUT request.
     */
    HttpPut httpRequest = new HttpPut(sHCPURLFilePath);


    FileInputStream dataFile = new FileInputStream(sBaseFileName + ".toHCP");
    System.out.println(dataFile.available());

    // Point the HttpRequest to the input stream.
    httpRequest.setEntity(new InputStreamEntity(dataFile, -1));

    // Set HTTP Authorization Header with HCP credentials.
    httpRequest.setHeader(HCPUtils.HTTP_AUTH_HEADER, "HCP" + sEncodedUserName + ":" + sEncodedPassword);
    System.out.println(HCPUtils.HTTP_AUTH_HEADER);
    System.out.println(sHCPURLFilePath);
    System.out.println(sEncodedUserName);
    System.out.println("HCP " + sEncodedUserName + ":" + sEncodedPassword);

    /*
     * Now execute the PUT request.
     */
    HttpResponse httpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(httpRequest);
```

The exception caused at the above line don't know what's the reason.Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Could you post some more codes?

Comment: It looks like you are compiling with one version of the Apache HTTP client library, but running your code with a different version. Make sure you use the same version of this library for compiling and running your code.